# CouchDB stale=update_after completion notification

Tags: couchdb

Is there a way to receive a notification by push or pull as to when the view has been updated? Ideally I want to be able to return the existing data to the user and then notify them when their new content is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is an explicit way to do what you are asking, but I had a few ideas for you:

## 1) Polling [_active_tasks](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/server/common.html?highlight=active%20tasks#get--_active_tasks)

You could try inspecting the active task list of the server, looking for an entry that matches: `type === indexer` and `design_document === _design/your-design-doc`. If your view is going to take minutes or more to finish updating, this could be worth a shot. (granted I've never actually tried this, but in theory it should work) This requires you to poll the server continuously.

## 2) Poll the view itself via `HEAD`

After issuing your first request, you could start polling using `HEAD` requests, waiting for the `ETag` header to change. (which indicates that the view index has been changed) `HEAD` requests are about as minimal as you can get, so this is probably a better option than #1)

## 3) Issue 2 GET requests (instead of using `stale=update_after`)

You could always just issue 2 requests, where the first one is `stale=ok` for the sake of speed. Then you just make a request immediately after that does not allow a stale result, which will take longer. It's not nearly as "flashy", but this will probably work the best.